# Finding oblique asymptotes of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm having troubles with finding oblique asymptotes of a function
$$ x-3\sqrt{4x^2+5} $$
This is what I did :
$$ x-3\sqrt{x^2(4+\frac{5}{x^2})} $$
So I thought I could assume that
$$ f(x) \approx x-3|x| $$
So I proceeded to finding asymptotes for
$$ -2x / 4x $$
The results are
$$ \frac {-2x} {x} = -2 $$
$$ \frac {4x} {x} = 4 $$
$$ -2x+2x = 0 $$
$$ 4x -4x = 0 $$
$$ y= -2x / y=4x $$
However Wolfram Alpha says the asymptote is $$ y=-5x $$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptote+x-3sqrt(4x%5E2%2B5)

What I possibly don't understand about finding oblique asymptotes for functions involving absolute values?

Comment: In the very beginning, you should factor out $(2x)^2$ from the radical.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(x)=x-6|x|$? (I know nothing about asymptotes, but it seems $\sqrt{4x^2+5} \approx 2x$).

Comment: How can I be sure what number should be factored out? $$ x-3\sqrt{x^2(4+\frac{5}{x^2})} | x-3\sqrt{2x^2(2+\frac{5}{2x^2})} | x-3\sqrt{4x^2(1+\frac{5}{4x^2})} $$ I think all of those representations are right, but they give different asymptotes?

Comment: Ok, it seems that square root out of 4 determined what should be factored out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $$y=x-3|x|\sqrt{4+\frac{5}{x^2}}$$

So for large positive $x$, we have $$y\simeq x-3(x)(2)\implies y\simeq-5x$$

And for large negative $x$, we have $$y\simeq x-3(-x)(2)\implies y\simeq 7x$$

Note that there must be two asymptotes since the curve is a hyperbola.

Comment: It should be y=7x for me, too. I think Wolfram Alpha fails to calculate asymptote from the "other" side.

Comment: Yes, so it seems. There may be some way of obtaining the other asymptote from WA but I don't know what that is.

Comment: This is not a mathematical proof.  How can you be sure that $y+5x$ and $y-7x$ tend to $0$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn try replacing x with -x and looking at that asymptote

Answer (score 0):

You fail to incorporate the radical part.  Notice that

$$\sqrt{4+\frac5{x^2}}\to\sqrt4=2$$

Answer (score 0):

2150056
Starting form.
$\quad y=x-3\sqrt{4x^2+5}$
Isolate radical term.
$\quad y-x=3\sqrt{4x^2+5}$
Square both sides.
$\quad (y-x)^2=9(4x^2+5)$
$\quad y^2-2xy+x^2=36x^2+45$
Implicit form.
$\quad 35x^2+2xy-y^2+45=0$
Substitute $y=mx+b.$
$\quad 35x^2+2x(mx+b)-(mx+b)^2+45=0$
$\quad 35x^2+2mx^2+2bx-m^2x^2-2mbx-b^2+45=0$
Extract coëfficients of $x^2,\quad x;$
equate them to $0;$
and solve for $m,\quad b.$
$\quad \left\{\begin{array}{l}
35+2m-m^2=0\\
-2mb=0
\end{array}\right.$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\text{case}&\{m\mid b\}&\to&mx+b=y&\to&\text{asymptote}\\
\hline
1&\{7\mid 0\}&\to&7x+0=y&\to&7x=y\\
2&\{-5\mid 0\}&\to&-5x+0=y&\to&-5x=y
\end{array}$